# how to distinguish which 'Enter' key was pressed?

Tags: javascript, keycode, enter, onkeypress

So I've got this textarea which listens for <kbd>Enter</kbd> keypress event. But I only want it to respond to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key being pressed on the number pad not the one next to the letters.

What's a method I can use?

Comment: That's going to be annoying for your users that don't have a number keypad.

Answer (score 3):

Both keys trigger the exactly same events with the same key code (13). It's not possible to differ between them in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

There is no different keyCode for nomal enter and enter on keypad. Its 13 in both cases

http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 1):

They actually do the same thing and are indistinguishable